# Error laravel 6 axios: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: axios, laravel-6

please I need you to help me with a problem in Server xampp, laravel 6 with axios, apparently it doesn't allow me to request ajax. attached image for more detail. Thanks in advance.

```
    methods: {
        loadEstados() {
            axios.get(`http://localhost/estados/pais/${this.selected_pais}`).then((response) => {                
                    this.careers = response.data;

                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);

            });
```

```
Route::get('estados/pais/{pais_id}', 'UsuarioController@getEstadosByPais');
```

```
   public function getEstadosByPais($pais_id)
   {
       if ($request->ajax()) {
           $estados = Estado::where('id', $pais_id)->get();

           foreach ($estados as $estado) {
               $estadoArray[$estado->id] = $estado->esta_nombre;
           }

           return response()->json($estadoArray);
       }
       //
   }
```

[browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aL8B.png)

Comment: sdfsdf dsfd sfdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found  the solution, the problem was how i put the address

in the web.php

`Route::get('estados/pais/', 'UsuarioController@getEstadosByPais');`

in the file js

```
        if (this.selected_pais !="") {
            axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:80/estados/pais`, 
            {params: {pais_id: this.selected_pais} }).then((response) => {
            this.estados = response.data;
            document.getElementById('estado').disabled =false;

            });
        }
```

in the file controller

```
public function getEstados(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $estados = Estado::where('id', $request->pais_id)->get();
        foreach ($estados as $estado) {
            $estadoArray[$estado->id] = $estado->esta_nombre;
        }

        return response()->json($estadoArray);
    }

}
```

Including port if necessary

thank you very much